# Processing Trigonometry Code Not Working

Tags: java, animation, rotation, processing, trigonometry

My processing code is based on the Oscillation chapter of *Nature Of Code* by Daniel Shiffman, mainly the examples where he rotates a mover according to the direction it is heading (the mouse).
It doesn't work, though I'm pretty sure its one little mistake somewhere. The rectangle just flies outside the screen.
Example from book (not full):

```java
void display() {
    float angle = velocity.heading2D;
    stroke(0); fill(175); pushMatrix(); rectMode(CENTER);              
    translate(location.x,location.y);
    rotate (angle); 
    rect(0,0,30,10);
    popMatrix();
}
```

My code :

```java
void show() {
    angle = velocity.heading2D();
    rectMode(CENTER);
    pushMatrix();
    translate(location.x,location.y);
    rotate(angle);

    fill(255,20,20,150);
    rect(location.x,location.y,carSize,carSize);
    popMatrix();
}
```

Setup and draw :

```java
Car car ;
void setup() {
    car = new Car();
}

void draw() {
    mouse = new PVector(mouseX,mouseY);
    background(255);
    car.show();
    car.move();
    car.update();
}
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? Instead of just posting your entire class without any `setup()` or `draw()` functions (which means we can't run your code), narrow your problem down to just a few example lines of code.

Comment: Sorry, I'll change it.

Comment: Also, i don't know what the translate(location.x,location.y) does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. Instead of

```
 translate(location.x,location.y);  
 rect(location.x,location.y,40,40);
```

It had to be :

```
 translate(location.x,location.y);  
 rect(0,0,40,40);
```

because the translate already takes the origin point to the object's location, and that's where I want to draw it (0,0).